# MVC ErrorHandling Attribute returning JSON results to ajax requests works only on localhost

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app I have the following Filter registered to handle unhandled errors. The server side returns a 500 error which is caught by the jquery error handler.

When I hit my page from the same machine as the host IIS I get the expected behavior where I get the error message in my json which I can display to the user. But when I try to hit my app from a different box I get a generic server error page. I have tried turning on/off the custom errors with no effects. The controller action is decorated with the error handler attribute.

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute :  FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { message = filterContext.Exception.Message },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need the following line added to the Exception handling filter for the default IIS 500 error handling to not kick in.

filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

The Filter now looks as follows

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { error = true,message = filterContext.Exception.Message },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```